# Running executable asynchronously from web application (safe solution)

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, executable

What are the alternatives to System.Diagnostics API for running external EXE or BAT files under IIS hosted web application? 
I would like to run external EXE program from my ASP.NET-MVC web application. I don't need to wait till the program exits. I just want to start the program. The execution can take some time or it may crash, so I would like to run it separatelly from IIS in such a way that the web application only triggers its execution.

Comment: just a question, why can't you use System.Diagnostic API?
System.Diagnostic allow you to start a new process, that is what you want..

Comment: @stefano: The new process will have IIS worker process as its parent. I'm not sure what could happen when child process crashes or allocates a lot of memory. I want the web application to be safe in such situation. That's the reason why I wan't to separate the execution of the EXE program.

Comment: Your child process will do no harm to the IIS worker process (unless your child process is explicitly searching for its parent and kills it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did once is create a WebService (the functionality was incapsulated in one anyways) and specified the method as "OneWay" which is basically a "Fire and Forget".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181848(v=vs.80).aspx

Your request goes without expecting a response from the server.

Surely enough you need to code your own "notification" logic to let the user know the success / failure of the task.

As @stefano mentioned in the comments you can use the Diagnostics.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

Since it will be in the OneWay setup your web app won't wait for the app to finish running before issuing the HttpResponse.